# Splitting String in a Column multiple times

Tags: string, pandas

I have a DF as shown below:

```
DF =

ID   T    R
1    A    ",Oa+,,Li+,,Wa+"
1    A    "Lo+,,Oa+,,Wa+"
1    A    ",Li+,,Wa+"
```

I want to create a new column with values from `R` that are at the beginning of a sentence until the delimiter "+" and the characters after the delimiter ",," until the delimiter "+". Meaning:

```
DF_New =

ID   T    R                     Re
1    A    ",Oa+,,Li+,,Wa+"      Oa,Li,Wa
1    A    "Lo+,,Oa+,,Wa+"       Lo,Oa,Wa
1    A    ",Li+,,Wa+"           Li,Wa
```

I need to change the following line of code to do that:

```
DF["Re"] = DF["R"].str.split('+').str[0]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your example, You could use `str.findall` to find all strings of letters (using the regex `\w+`, which matches one or more word characters), and `str.join` to join them together:

```
df['Re'] = df.R.str.findall('(\w+)').str.join(',')

>>> df
   ID  T               R        Re
0   1  A  ,Oa+,,Li+,,Wa+  Oa,Li,Wa
1   1  A   Lo+,,Oa+,,Wa+  Lo,Oa,Wa
2   1  A       ,Li+,,Wa+     Li,Wa
```

Answer (score 2):

If need to strip only `+` and `,` (or other specific values), use `agg`

```
vals = '+,'
df.R.str.split(',').agg(lambda x: ', '.join(z.strip(vals) for z in x if z.strip(vals)))

0    Oa, Li, Wa
1    Lo, Oa, Wa
2        Li, Wa
```